# BlockingCollection TryTake C#

Tags: c#

Делаю так:

```
Event evnt = null;
            try
            {
                if (!queueEvents.TryTake(out evnt, 0, token))
                {
                    // Очередь пуста, ожидаем.                    
                    await Task.Delay(timeout);                     
                }
                else
                {
                    // Обработка события                        
                     ProcessEvent(evnt);                                            
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Taking canceled.");
                break;
            }
```

Иногда попадаю в ветку else, но при этом evnt остается null, что не так?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас в очередь добавлен был элемент значение которого null.

Comment: @АлексейЛосев точно! Проверю!

Comment: @АлексейЛосев Вы были правы, спасибо!